# Jasmine Testing Anonymous

Tags: javascript, jasmine, anonymous-function

I am writing a test suite with the following code:

```
it("succeeds", function(){
    var o = {}
    o.f = function() { console.log("event caught!");}
    spyOn(o, "f").and.callThrough();
    addEventListener('click', function() {o.f;});
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
    expect(o.f).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This test fails telling me that f was not called, but if instead of

```
addEventListener('click', function() {o.f;});
```

I write

```
addEventListener('click', o.f);
```

the test succeeds. 
I understand the problem is with having an anonymous function enclosing the other function, but I don't know how to rewrite the test.

Comment: You forget to call a function addEventListener('click', function() {o.f();});

Comment: Try changing `addEventListener('click', function() {o.f;});` to `addEventListener('click', function() {o.f();});`

Comment: Or may be `addEventListener('click', o.f)`